# I want to integrate a rational function, with the method for rationals mentioned below, I'm attending Calculus I at University

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}$ which result $\frac{1}{4} \log|x-1|- \frac{1}{4}\log|x+1|-\frac{1}{2}\arctan x$

so for polynomial identity, and because $x^2+1$ doesn't have real roots:

$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}= \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-1} + \frac{2Cx+D}{x^2+1}$

then I find A and B, I find A moltiplying for both sides by $(x+1)$:
$\frac{1(x+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}= A + \frac{B(x+1)}{x-1} + \frac{(2Cx+D)(x+1)}{x^2+1}$

and then placing $x=-1$ so A=$-\frac{1}{4}$.
Repeating for B the same, $B=\frac{1}{4}$

To find $C$ and $D$:

I place $x=0$ and $x=2$:

$x=0:$ $$-\frac{1}{1}= -\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} + D$$

and for $x=2$
$$\frac{1}{3\times5}= -\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4C+\frac{3}{2}}{4+1}$$

so $D=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $C=-\frac{1}{2}$

Now I can rewrite:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)} = \frac{1}{4} \log|x-1|- \frac{1}{4}\log|x+1|+ \int\frac{-x-\frac{1}{2}}{x^2+1}dx$$

which result:

$$\frac{1}{4} \log|x-1|- \frac{1}{4}\log|x+1|-\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\arctan x$$

So it seems to becorrect but I had a factor of $-\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+1)$ that I can't clear

Comment: @Moo of course, I understand that $2Cx+D$ necessarily are equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ but why? Because $x^2+1$ has not real roots, and x has grade 2 so it must be 2Cx+D and not only C or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From
$$
\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}= \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-1} + \frac{2Cx+D}{x^2+1}
$$
you found
$A=-\frac14$, $B=\frac14$, and $D=-\frac12.$
So
$$
\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}
= -\frac{1}{4(x+1)} + \frac{1}{4(x-1)} + \frac{2Cx-\frac12}{x^2+1}.
$$
For $x=2$ this gives you
$$
\frac{1}{15}
= -\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4C-\frac12}{5}.
$$

But you wrote the last term as
$$
\frac{4C+\frac32}{5}.
$$

Fix that error and you should get the correct result.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for this trivial miscalculation, I appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We can easily resolve it into partial fraction piece by piece as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\left(x^2-1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)} & =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{4(x-1)}-\frac{1}{4(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2\left(x^2+1\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back yields $$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{\left(x^2-1\right) \cdot\left(x^2+1\right)} & =\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{d x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{d x}{(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d x}{x^2+1} \\
& =\frac{1}{4} \ln |x-1|-\frac{1}{4} \ln |x+1|-\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1} x+C
\end{aligned}
$$